# How do i check Authentification in the Controller Index Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

everyone, I am fairly new to laravel I am currently working on a HR System project and I am creating a Leave managment where the user employee can ask for a leave of sort and the manager and admin can accept or deny it and it was going pretty well until at some point i dont know why but the user can still see what the admin should see he can still enter through the link even when the files are in the admin folder so i tried to do an if with Auth but it wasnt working and its giving me this error

"Trying to get property 'role_id' of non-object"

This is the code im using for the if in the index

LeaveController

```
public function index()
    {
        $leaves = Leave::latest()->get();

       if(Auth::user()->role_id == 1){
        return view('/home');
       }
       elseif(Auth::user()->role_id == 2){
        return view('admin/leave/index', compact('leaves'));
       }
       else{
           return view('admin/leave/index', compact('leaves'));
       }
        
    }
```

Employee has a role based id 1 and Manager has role id of 2 but the super admin doesnt have it he just exists like a default admin with all permissions thats why i just left it at else

Comment: Welcome to SO ... the admin doesn't have a role? what marks them as an admin? is there a field on the user table that declares them an admin? is admin a model different then the user model?

Comment: Yes!! The admin has its own table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have check if someone is an admin to continue the page you can make a middleware.

```
php artisan make:middleware CheckAdmin

Route::get('admin/profile', function () {
    //
})->middleware('Admin');
```

and on the web.php file attach the middleware to the route.

Check the laravel docs for detailed information
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I already have a checkAdmin middleware how would I use that to that part of the code?

Comment: In your web.php
Route::resource('/admin/post', 'PostController')->middleware(['adminpass']);
something like this

Comment: Thanks i just don't seem to understand it or im just doing it very wrong ill try to watch a tutorial about it or something until i get it thank you

Comment: No problem, you can ask questions to me i can help you, if you feel like this answered helped you feel free to mark is as best and upvote.